# What creates the experience of "erasure" in visual perception?

Tags: vision, consciousness

When I was reading about [object substitution masking](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Object_substitution_masking), the author mentioned that sometimes we experience "erasure" of masked object. I sometimes have this kind of experience myself. It looks like the object was there but then became erased by the mask. How this effect is called properly and what creates such experience? I'll be grateful for the links to relevant papers.